# Was sagt man bei einem Foto?

Tags: single-word-request

Welcher Spruch ist üblich, wenn viele Menschen fotografiert werden, sie wissen ja, damit sie so scheinen als würden sie lachen. Und gibt es regionale Unterschiede?

Comment: My kids' current favourite: "Ameisenscheiiiiiiße"

Comment: Mr. Conehead uses "Laktatextrakt". ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no widely used equivalent to the ubiquitous English "cheese" in German.

What I have sometimes heard in my childhood is *Spaghetti*. [Various](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Say_cheese) [sources](https://www.gutefrage.net/frage/was-kann-man-alternativ-zu-cheese-als-fotograf-noch-sagen) [confirm](https://life-is-a-trip.com/say-cheese-weltweit/) [this](http://www.sueddeutsche.de/leben/studie-das-perfekte-kameralaecheln-gymnastik-fuer-die-mundwinkel-1.1030114) and add some alternatives:

```
Spaghetti [with a long i]
Käsekuchen [with a long ä]
Wurst [personally, I haven't heard of this]
Ameisenscheiße [with a long ei]
cheese [just as in the US]
```

It is also common to just omit a phrase that forces a smile, and signal that a picture is going to be taken with [other phrases](https://www.omniglot.com/language/phrases/saycheese.htm), eg

```
Wo ist das Vögelchen? [for children]
(Bitte) Lächeln
```

Comment: Just imagining the facial expression of a crowd saying "Kääääääse" or "Wuuuuurst"....

Comment: Cheese habe ich schon oft gehört. Der Rest ist mir unbekannt.

Comment: Wurst?! Ein Blick in den Spiegel beim Aussprechen des Wortes bringt bei mir Zweifel an der Eignung für gestellte Fotografien hervor. Der Vokal u wird nicht mit einer fürs Fotografieren vorteilhaften Mundstellung erzeugt.

Comment: @harper Ich kenne es wie gesagt auch nicht. Evtl wird das r (oder s) langgezogen? Passt auch jeden Fall besser als u. Oder es kommt aus einer Region wo Menschen ganz ganz anders lächeln.

Comment: Ich verwende immer "Gemüse".